# Check connection and reconnect wifi

Tags: wireless, bash

I'm building a wireless photoframe. The one thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to get my wifi connection back up using a recommended method.

Right now I edited /etc/network/interfaces so wlan0 is started at boot:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wireless-essid ourssid
```

This method works fine for booting. But I found that if I do not check the connection for a long time (could be a week) it might be down. So I should reconnect.

What I do now to verify the connection is working is downloading a file from the server that can't be cached (http://server.ext/ping.php?randomize=123456)
If I fail to retrieve the file I assume that the connection is no longer working and I run a shell script like

```
#!/bin/bash
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 essid "ourssid"
dhclient wlan0
```

And the connection comes back. But I can't find anything if this is in any way a good method.

Can this be improved upon, or is this already right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifup wlan0` should do all that for you automatically.

It reads the `interfaces` file and does everything that startup would do. You may have to run `ifdown wlan0` first if `ifup` believes the interface is already up.

You could make a small script to try getting the file and then run `ifup` if it fails and cron it for every hour or two.

Answer (score 4):

I found the following script at http://sirlagz.net/2013/01/10/script-wifi-checker-script/

- Just create a new file `vi /root/checkwanup`:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  wlan=`/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 | grep inet\ addr | wc -l`

  if [ $wlan -eq 0 ]; then
  /sbin/ifdown wlan0 && /sbin/ifup wlan0
  else
  echo interface is up
  fi
  ```
- Then `chmod 555 /root/checkwanup`
- Add it to your crontab

  ```
  crontab -e
  */15 * * * * /bin/bash /root/checkwanup
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I had to use: `/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 up` and `/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 down`